# C# : Building or getting latest keeps adding entity 5 to packages while project has been upgraded to 6

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-5, entity-framework-6

After having updated a project using Nuget to Entity 6.1.3., this project keeps adding a package for Entity 5.0.0. when Getting latest of that project or when building it.
I already looked with low-level search (fileseek) but can't find any reference anymore in that project to EF5.
Already uninstalled the Entity package and reinstalled, but same result.
What else can I do to compeltely remove any reference to EF5 ?

Comment: Please follow the MSDN article,  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/upgradeef6.aspx

1. Ensure that assembly references to System.Data.Entity.dll are removed.

2. Swap any EF Designer (EDMX) models to use EF 6.x code generation.

3. Update namespaces for any core EF types being used.

Comment: I followed all those instructions when I performed the update.
Problem is solved in the meantime : there was an unloaded! project in which the packages.config still referenced the 5.0.0 framework.
I didn't know that an unloaded project was still held into account when building.

Answer (score 0):

Problem is solved in the meantime : there was an unloaded! project in which the packages.config still referenced the 5.0.0 framework. I didn't know that an unloaded project was still held into account when building.